# R reading csv file i want to only one column with that row end with specific string value

Tags: r, csvreader

[image]** above image showing sample data list, so i want to get only record that content specific keyword end like (contact); on that row. **

```
data <- read.csv("csv.csv", sep = ',')

# Get the max salary from data frame.
Piname <- data$col_NAME
print(Piname)
poname <- Piname[str_detect(Piname,"(end_string);")]
print(poname)

#summary(warnings())

tail(warnings(), 50)
```

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example.  Try with `str_detect(Piname,fixed("(end_string);)")`

Comment: BRYAN, ROBERT M; MCCULLOUGH, LOUISE D. (contact);

 this the example data line i want only end with  (contact);

Comment: Try `"\\(contact\\);"`

Comment: here it shows anywhere in content (contact); but i want to only end with

Comment: It would be ` "\\(contact\\);$"`

Comment: I guess you don't want the `FISHEL`..  or `KORF`, row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can either escape the `()` `\\(contact\\);$` and use it as pattern

```
Piname[str_detect(Piname, "\\(contact\\);$")]
```

as by default, the `(` or `)` would be recognized as metacharacters to capture the characters as a group.  The `$` is a metacharacter to signify the end of string

Comment: Piname[str_detect(Piname, fixed("(contact);$"))]  

for this, i am not getting any data output

Comment: @CoderS  I removed the `fixed` as you want to use regex `$` please check my update